# Which documents should I include when reapplying for a UK visa after a refusal linked to fund transfers between my and my mother's accounts?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

In my initial UK tourist visa application, it was refused due to an inadvertent error in my financial documentation (My bank statements). I had temporarily transferred funds to my mother's account, which were then returned to mine. Both transactions are reflected in the bank statements provided, with the names on both accounts corresponding to my mother's and mine.

On December 25th, 2023, I transferred £10,000 from my account to my mother's for safekeeping, as she typically manages my finances and holds a savings account on my behalf. This decision was made solely for convenience and security cause I'm still young, single and not so good at managing finance.

On February 22nd, 2024, in preparation for my visa application, my mother transferred the funds back to my account. This might sound like "funds parking", but theoretically it's originated from my own money

I seek guidance on rectifying this and demonstrating that the transfer originated from my stated income, with no additional undisclosed funds. While I cannot merge my mother's account with mine, should I clarify that the transfer was supported by my mother's financial assistance? even though I'm fully aware this is untrue from my perspective, but might be legally correct.

Could anyone please give me some advices on this ? Thanks.

Comment: Don’t over think this. The obvious and simplest solution is to provide additional bank statements that show the origin of the £10,000 balance. Eg did you build the balance up over several months of saving prior to Dec 25th, or did it come from a one-off event such as a bonus or an investment maturity, or maybe a tax refund or an insurance payout? Providing 6 months’ statements is typical but more may be needed to demonstrate source of funds

Comment: If the funds originated from a one-off event, provide evidence of that in addition to the bank statements.

Comment: Thanks @Traveller. Yes, the balance was accumulated through saving leading up to December 25th, primarily from my regular income sources